# How to create this image of a simulated finished needlepoint

Tags: adobe-illustrator, adobe-photoshop, filter, embroidery

[image]

Hi,

I am looking for any tips on how this person made this image. It seems like a filter of some kind used with a pixel image of a cat. The trick is each "stitch" is different so it is not just a single overlay applied to each pixel.

Any suggestions are helpful.